# How to convert my select statement into update statement?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT quotes.qid, SUM(qitems.net_cost_ext)
FROM quotes, qitems
WHERE quotes.qid = qitems.qid
GROUP BY qitems.qid;

UPDATE quotes, qitems
SET quotes.net_cost_total = SUM(qitems.net_cost_ext)
WHERE quotes.qid = qitems.qid
GROUP BY qitems.qid;
```

The above select statements sums up the net cost for all the products on each quote and displays the sum by quote number.

I added a net_cost_total field to the quotes table. I want to update all the quotes with the net_cost totals from each quote. The query fails, it says the GROUP syntax is bad, I'm not sure how else to go about this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this one:

```
UPDATE quotes AS q 
        JOIN (SELECT quotes.qid, 
                         SUM(qitems.net_cost_ext) AS SUM 
                  FROM   quotes, 
                         qitems 
                  WHERE  quotes.qid = qitems.qid 
                  GROUP  BY qitems.qid) AS d 
         ON d.qid = q.qid 
SET    q.net_cost_total = d.SUM
```

Comment: This solution works great. I didn't know joins could do that... I've always used them for simple table joins. If I understand correctly your creating a custom version of the qitems table based off the select statement in the join statement...

Comment: It is called derived table from a select. That () encloses actually a virtual table.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
UPDATE quotes
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT SUM(qitems.net_cost_ext) AS s
    FROM qitems
    GROUP BY qitems.qid
  ) q USING(qid)
SET net_cost_total = q.s
```

(inspired from the last MySQL comment [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html))

Answer (score 0):

Using Standard SQL:

```
UPDATE quotes
   SET net_cost_total = (
                         SELECT SUM(net_cost_ext)
                           FROM qitems
                          WHERE quotes.qid = qitems.qid
                        )
 WHERE EXISTS (
               SELECT *
                 FROM qitems
                WHERE quotes.qid = qitems.qid
              );
```